# Do F-22 Raptors have different chemical colored coatings on the canopy?

Tags: aircraft-design, us-air-force, f-22, canopy

Today I saw an image of a couple of Raptors parked at Spangdahelm AFB and I noticed that one of the Raptors in the image had Golden-tinted canopy glass while the other one had orange-tinted Canopy Glass. I've also seen some images of F-22s at Elmendorf with the orange/reddish canopy glass tint similar to that of the F-35s canopy. I always thought the raptor had the gold tint, but this picture proves it wrong because it's pretty clear to see the difference in tint at the same angle. I'm also curious if it's ever been stated which chemical is used for the orange/pinkish tint since it's been said previously that the gold tint used on some raptors is Indium Tin Oxide.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the original source of your bottom photo? Looks like cgi to me; is it?

Comment: @RalphJ I really thought so too, but it's from real DoD footage: see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=38caG8VztBc) at timestamp 3:14. The still image is heavily postprocessed with dynamic contrast compared to the video.

Comment: I would think that the differences in the first picture could be explained by differences in cloud cover. You'd be _shocked_ at what the slightest change in lighting will do to a photograph. Even the light bouncing off the side of 088 will effect the color of the reflection on 079's canopy.

Comment: @FreeMan since I didn't want to post the full picture because it would make the Raptors look harder to see, but there is a full image with 4 Raptors in the picture (2 just cropped out in this image) 1 raptor too had the orange tint and the other next to it had a gold tint. I don't think it would be clouds considering those two cropped out were further away from these with the same tints.

Comment: @FreeMan sidenote: I found a vid that shows the Raptors landing in germany with obvious differences in tint despite weather. https://youtu.be/AAf_dTVcoms

Comment: Even _very_ slight differences in lighting can make a _huge_ difference in the appearance of color. Go hang out at [photo.se] for a bit and look through some of the lighting questions. When you're outdoors under natural lighting, it changes moment by moment and _no_ picture is perfectly evenly lit.

Answer (score 3):

No, all canopies manufactured for the F-22A aircraft are done in an identical fashion. It’s just lighting reflecting off the canopy at different angles, different backgrounds behind them, etc.

It might also be possible that one represents a later production example  of the F-22, where the indium oxide coating process on the canopy was altered and improved for whatever reason (better durability, reduced RCS, etc.).

Comment: There is a video of the f-22s landing and taxiing with obvious differences in tint same weather and same timing (check my response to FreeMan). I'm aware all Raptors had the Indium tin Oxide tint from the start of manufacturing, but I'm still not convinced this orange tint appearence is in the case of lighting. I'd assume the raptor has received some sort of RCS related upgrades recently, and if you notice there aren't as many recently taken images of F-22s with golden canopies unlike back then.

Comment: Look carefully in a lot of these videos and photographs, you’ll notice that the aircraft with a darker tint to the canopy are also placed in front of a darker background. I suspect this has a dramatic effect on how the camera captures light from the canopies.

Comment: I saw two F-22's last week at Easterwood Airport (CLL) in College Station, Texas. They had done a flyover with two F-16's the previous Saturday at nearby Texas A&M University during the national anthem for the Aggies vs. Alabama game. I took [this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfkzT.jpg) on Tuesday when the two F-16's and one of the F-22's left. I saw the closer F-22 on multiple days, it always had the orange tint, sort of rose colored also which the photo picked up more on. Imgur won't show the photo details but my phone says that the photo was taken at 11:35 am on October 10th.

Comment: Interesting.  But the aircraft in the photos are F-35s not F-22s

Comment: @carlofelicione - I knew that! Or at least I did last week when I saw them and wondered about the unusual canopy color. I must have been thrown by the question on the same topic. So it seems like both F-22 and F-35 have something similar going on, as the orange/pink description matches very close to what I saw on the F-35's.